# React SSR giving Element type is invalid error

Tags: server-side-rendering, react-18

I am trying to implement React 18 SSR using renderToPipeableStream API. When I hit the url on localhost it throws below error:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Here is my server.js file:

```
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  const entryPoint = ["/main.js"];

  const { pipe, abort: _abort } = ReactDOMServer.renderToPipeableStream(
    <App />,
    {
      bootstrapScripts: entryPoint,
      onShellReady() {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
        pipe(res);
      },
      onShellError() {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.send("<!doctype html><p>Loading...</p>");
      },
    }
  );
});

app.listen(3002, () => {
  console.log("App is running on http://localhost:3002");
});
```

Here is my App.js:
const App = () => {
return (


Hello

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
  </Routes>
</div>
```

);
};

export default App;